# Selector, templateUrl, styleUrls not working inside component for Angular-cli version 6.2.9 and Angular 6.1.10

Tags: angular, components, angular6, angular-components

Hi I am trying to use Selector, templateUrl and styeUrls inside Component in my ts file. I am able to load the html file but y css is not getting applied.

Please find my ts code below.

```
 @Component({
     selector: 'app-entity-registration',
     templateUrl: './entity-registration.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./entity-registration.component.css']
 })
```

[My code structure inside src - app - root - Myproject - pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI0ov.png)

The error which i am get while placing my cursor is :

```
[ts]
Argument of type '{selector: string; tmplateUrl: string; styleUrls:string[]; }' is not assignable parameter of type 'Component'.
Property 'true' is missing in type '{selector: strig; templateUrl: string; styleUrl:strig[];}'
```

I am hanged with this error for 2 days... Please help  me in resolving.

Please find the below version of packages i am using.

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.9
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.8.9
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.9
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.9
@angular/cdk                      7.3.1
@angular/cli                      6.2.9
@angular/material                 7.3.1
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.9
@schematics/angular               0.8.9
@schematics/update                0.8.9
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.16.4
```

Comment: strange.. is your code compiling ?

Comment: yes my code is compiling. @programoholic

Comment: what is the typescript version you are using ?

Comment: in vs code switch to your  project version of TS. It will fade away

Comment: it's placed at bottom right corner in VS code like . `typescript 2.7.1`

Comment: Should I change my Visual Studio Code version or my typescript @programoholic

Comment: Can you please tell me like how to switch my project version of TS in Visual studio.

Comment: you just switch.. click on the typescript version and choose your version

Comment: @programoholic I have switched my typescript version. but still my css is not getting applied. and my error has faded away after switching the version.

Comment: can you please produce stackblitz. to help you further